# Accessing the result of a returned promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to understand promises better and have implemented code that basically looks like this:

```js
console.log(getRemoteData())

function getRemoteData (){
  return fetch('http://w.x.y.z')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}
```

Assuming that `getRemoteData()` returns a promise, how do I access the value of that response? I've tried to resolve the promise before logging to the console and I can't get it to do anything but log the promise obj. I think I'm missing a fundamental component of how promises work.

I've tried searching SO and all the answers I find point to a `//do something with the returned data` comment in the `.then()` method but I'd like to learn what I should do from there. The returned value is an `array[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch(...)` returns a promise, and `response.json()` returns another promise.

The returned value is not an array but a *promise* of an array. It should be:

```
getRemoteData().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

The structure can be flattened similarly to synchronous code in `async` functions (ES2017). They are syntactic sugar for promises, this snippet is equal to the previous one:

```
(async () => {
    const result = await getRemoteData();
    console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: Ahh, this is incredibly helpful, thanks! Is there a reason why I can't `return result` to the outer `console.log()` call instead of doing so within the returned promise?

Comment: Because getRemoteData is asynchronous, and there's no result at the moment when it's called. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for some ideas, it covers a lot of things including promises.

Answer (score 1):

Or use [co](https://github.com/tj/co) if you are still on ES2015

```
var co = require('co');

co(function *(){
    // yield any promise
    var result = yield getRemoteData();
}).catch(onerror);
```